# $1^n-3^n-6^n+8^n$ is divisible by $10$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility

Prove that $1^n-3^n-6^n+8^n$ is divisible by $10$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

It is divisible by $2$ and $5$ if we rearrange it will it be enough

$(1^n -3^n)$ and $(6^n -8^n)$ is divisible by $2$. 
And
$(1^n-6^n)$ and $(8^n-3^n)$ is divisible by $5$.

Hence $\gcd(2,5)$ is $1$ and it is divisible by $2\cdot5=10$.

Is it correct?

Comment: Try setting equal to some $10X$, $X\in \mathbb{N}$ and then using proof by induction

Comment: In terms of your proof, that is not enough. $6$ is divisible by $2$, and $15$ is divisible by $5$, but $6+15=21$ which is *not* divisible by $10$

Comment: But here it is same and it is $1^n-3^n-6^n+8^n$

Comment: @RhysHughes The proof is correct. user8933: very astute!

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, what I was saying is not that the statement is wrong, but that the OP's proof of it is...

Comment: @RhysHughes But the proof is correct, as I wrote. Maybe incomplete, as stated in a comment below, but the missing steps are almost obvious ($a^n-b^n$ should ring a bell). You seemed to miss the point of the proof: if $2|(1^n-3^n)$ and $2|(6^n-8^n)$, then $2$ divides the difference. Likewise with $5$, so the expression is a multiple of $10$. That's all.

Comment: Ah. I see it now.

Answer (score 1):

Note: $p,q,r,s,t, a ,b,  n \in \mathbb{N},$

$f(n):= (8^n-3^n) - (6^n-1^n)= (8-3)p-(6-1)q=5(p-q).$

On the other hand:

$f(n)= (8^n-6^n) -(3^n-1^n)=(8-6)r -(3-1)s=2(r-s)$

Hence:

$f(n)=5(p-q)=2(r-s).$

Euclid's Lemma:

$2$ divides $(p-q)$, i.e.

$p-q=2t$.

Combining:

$f(n)= 5\cdot 2 t.$

Used:

$(a^n-b^n)=$

$(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+.....+b^{n-1}).$

$p,q,r$ and $s$ were used for the above second factor.

Euclid's Lemma:

If a prime $p$ divides $ab$, then $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides $b$.

Comment: It is worth noting I think, that this is just a well dressed version of OPs proof. And so to answer the question, their proof is valid, but leaves much to be desired. (Also a^n - b^n in your polynomial equality line)

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is OK, however, for completeness, you must further show why the binomials are divisible by $2$ and $5$.

If you are familiar with modular arithmetic, it is:
$$1^n-3^n-6^n+8^n\equiv 1-3-6+8\equiv 0 \pmod {10}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Try a proof by induction.

Base Case: $n=1 \to 1-3-6+8=0$ which is divisible by $10$. So true for $n=1$

Then assume it true for some $n=k$; so:
$$1^k-3^k-6^k+8^k=10t, t\in \Bbb Z$$
Then use that fact to show it true for $n=k+1$: i.e, prove that:
$$1^{k+1}-3^{k+1}-6^{k+1}+8^{k+1}=10u, u \in \Bbb Z$$
For this, I would use that $n^{k+1}=n(n^k)$

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see the solution is by using 
$$a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2+...+a^2b^{n-3}+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})\tag{1}$$
leading to
$$1^n-3^n-6^n+8^n=(8^n-3^n)-(6^n-1^n)=\\
(8-3)(8^{n-1}+8^{n-2}\cdot3+...+8\cdot3^{n-2}+3^{n-1})-\\
(6-1)(6^{n-1}+6^{n-2}\cdot1+...+6\cdot1^{n-2}+1^{n-1})=...$$
we can see that $8^{n-1}+8^{n-2}\cdot3+...+8\cdot3^{n-2}$ is always **even** and so it $6^{n-1}+6^{n-2}\cdot1+...+6\cdot1^{n-2}$ then
$$...=5(2m+3^{n-1})-5(2n+1)=5\left(2(m-n)+3^{n-1}-1\right)$$
and $3^{n-1}-1$ is **even** from the same application of $(1)$, thus we can "extract" a 2 from $\left(2(m-n)+3^{n-1}-1\right)$ and the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps another method to notice is that, by Euler's Generalization of Fermat's Little Theorem, we have that:
$$1^n-3^n-6^n+8^n \equiv 1^{n \mod \phi(10)} - 3^{n \mod \varphi(10)} - 6^{n \mod \varphi(10)} + 8^{n \mod \varphi(10)} \mod 10$$
Since $\varphi(10) = 4$, you really only need to check the cases of $n = 0, 1, 2$ and $3$. For $n = 0$, you have:
$$1^0-3^0-6^0+8^0 \equiv 1 - 1 - 1 + 1 \equiv 0 \mod 10$$
For $n = 1$:
$$1^1-3^1-6^1+8^1 \equiv 1 - 3 - 6 + 8 \equiv 0 \mod 10$$
For $n = 2$:
$$1^2-3^2-6^2+8^2 \equiv 1 - 9 - 36 + 64 \equiv 20 \equiv 0 \mod 10$$
For $n = 3$:
$$1^3-3^3-6^3+8^3 \equiv 1 - 27 - 216 + 512 \equiv 270 \equiv 0 \mod 10$$
Since all the other exponents leading forward will be one of these cases, you are done. It is not the most elegant way to prove this, however, it is fairly direct.